# Garbage Collection ETW Events. Where do I find 'event data'

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, etw, xperf

In the following msdn link, there is 'event data' listed like Count, Depth, Reason ..
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#gcstart_v1_event

According to this link, I created a .etl file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264809.aspx

Using xprefview.exe I observed the etl file and even found the desired event 'GCStart_V1', looking at the column opcode in view 'summary table'.

Question: Where do I find the 'event data' that is listed in the first link?

Answer (score 1):

Use [PerfView](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567) instead because it is optimized for .net.
Here are some videos how to use it:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial